# parse JSON URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am stuck in json parsing url. I am not getting any data from parsing this json url. I want to get "ask" and "bid" from this json. http://www.fxgrow.com/quotes/quotes.php

its structure is:

```
{
EURUSD: {
dir: 1,
ask: "1.13960",
bid: "1.13955"
},
USDJPY: {
dir: 1,
ask: "118.928",
bid: "118.925"
},
USDCHF: {
dir: 1,
ask: "0.94488",
bid: "0.94459"
},
GBPUSD: {
dir: 1,
ask: "1.54351",
bid: "1.54342"
},
AUDUSD: {
dir: 0,
ask: "0.77653",
bid: "0.77648"
},
NZDUSD: {
dir: 1,
ask: "0.75169",
bid: "0.75158"
},
GBPJPY: {
dir: 1,
ask: "183.564",
bid: "183.553"
},
EURGBP: {
dir: 1,
ask: "0.73836",
bid: "0.73829"
}
}
```

my javascript code is:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.fxgrow.com/quotes/quotes.php", function(data) {
    alert(data.msg);
});`
```

Comment: Well first issue is it is a cross domain call so JavaScript in the browser is not going to be able to fetch it.

Comment: Are you getting console error like this `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.fxgrow.com/quotes/quotes.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `

Comment: yes I am. I tried to decode Json using php but I was stuck in how to get the data from php to javascript. any help plz @Rakesh_Kumar

Comment: Google for add `--disable-web-security` to google chrome and restart chrome. That will help. Once that done, just make minor change in your code and it will work.. `$.getJSON("http://www.fxgrow.com/quotes/quotes.php", function(data) {
    alert(data.EURGBP.dir);
});`

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar should I include any jquery files ?

Comment: @Kevink5 yes..else how you expect this `$.getJSON()` to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/yumq1mzu/1/

Just clone the shortcut for chrome you have on your desktop, and then in the shortcut properties add the parameter `--disable-web-security` at the end of chrome executable path like below:

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security`

Restart your chrome, and, make this change in your code:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.fxgrow.com/quotes/quotes.php", function(data) {
    alert(data.EURGBP.dir);   // alert 1
});
```

for below JSON

`{
"EURUSD":{"dir":1,"ask":"1.13679","bid":"1.13674"},
"USDJPY":{"dir":1,"ask":"118.995","bid":"118.990"},
"USDCHF":{"dir":1,"ask":"0.94957","bid":"0.94940"},
"GBPUSD":{"dir":1,"ask":"1.54205","bid":"1.54195"},
"AUDUSD":{"dir":1,"ask":"0.77893","bid":"0.77887"},
"NZDUSD":{"dir":1,"ask":"0.75185","bid":"0.75175"},
"GBPJPY":{"dir":1,"ask":"183.496","bid":"183.483"},
"EURGBP":{"dir":1,"ask":"0.73724","bid":"0.73716"}
}`